# Pydantic private argument for recursive model instantiation

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a Pydantic Model which is basically a list of other Models, as the following:

```py
class Thing(BaseModel):
    _api: Api = PrivateAttr()
    id: int
    name: str

class ThingList(BaseModel):
    _api: API = PrivateAttr()
    __root__ = List[Thing]
```

These things are parsed from the JSON contents of API calls I make to an external API, for example:

```py
def some_method_somewhere(self, api, **other_args)
    ...
    response = await api.send('GET', url)
    return ThingList(__root__=response, api=api)
```

However, I don't see how I can have the Pydantic instantiation of the `Thing` model receive the `api` argument.

Only easy way I can see is having some function return a global value I can call from `PrivateAttr(default_factory=func)`, but that smells.

This functionality should be as generic as possible. Currently ThingList could be replaced by a normal list by iterating over the Response object (feel free to pretend it comes from requests), but that's not guaranteed true in the future. (In fact, it's likely other attributes will come from the API that might need to be integrated into ThingList).

My dream solution would be extending a method somewhere in the ThingList class, but I can't find how Pydantic does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update nested objects private attributes in `__init__` method of enclosing model:

```
class Thing(BaseModel):
    _api: str = PrivateAttr()
    id: int
    name: str


class ThingList(BaseModel):
    _api: str = PrivateAttr()
    __root__: List[Thing]

    def __init__(self, *, api, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        self._api = api
        for item in self.__root__:
            item._api = api
```

Comment: That's promising. Would it get me in trouble with the validators, though, because it doesn't exist at initialization?

Comment: Perhaps, in the case of validators, it would be nice to see a minimal example of your use case.

Comment: I was thinking about pydantic default validators. But i've run the code with your suggestion, and they don't complain about post-instantiation assignment. So that's all right.